# Getting a submatrix of a larger matrix

Tags: matrix

This should be straightforward, but the Mathematica documentation does not seem to help with this. Suppose I have a $10 \times 10$ matrix and want to get the $3 \times3$ submatrix define by the intersections of rows $1,4,7$ with columns $2,4,6$. How would I do this? (For such a small matrix, it could be done by hand, but I will be needing to work with much larger ones for which manually doing such things would be unweildly) I think $Span[[;]]$ would be helpful, but doesn't immediately apply since the rows and columns are not adjacent.

Comment: Something like: `Array[a, {10, 10}][[1 ;; 7 ;; 3, 2 ;; 6 ;; 2]]`?

Comment: `arr[[{1, 4, 7}, {2, 4, 6}]]`